# In Civilization do players discard defeated army cards at the end of a battle?

Tags: civilization-board-game

In Civilization, at the end of a battle, do players discard defeated army cards or do the defeated army cards return to the players' hands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the rules of the base game (p. 25), eliminated unit cards are discarded and put face up under the appropriate deck on the market board.  Any unit cards not eliminated during the battle return to their owners (this is true for both the winner and the loser of the battle).

Comment: So it's possibletaht at some point in the game a user looses all his cards. What happends then if someone engage another combat against him ?

Comment: In this case the player "fights" with his military bonus alone. It is even possible that this bonus is sufficient to win the battle, which is a scenario covered by [FAQ 2.0, p. 4](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/news/Civilization%20FAQ_v2.0.pdf).